# How to divide data on Cluster in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have 1 cluster with 2 nodes mean 1 master and 2 slaves(slave1,slave2) and I have a text file (input.txt 1GB). Block size of hdfs is 64MB.

I want to do wordcount of input file.

First I copy input.txt on hdfs on master node using

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal input.txt /
```

then

```
hadoop jar Wordcount.jar Wordcount /input.txt /output
```

My questions are

1) Above commands are right to do Wordcount on cluster or wrong?

2) When I copy input.txt file it will store is slave 1 and slave2 datanode or master node?

3)Or I have to first copy input.txt on slave1 and slave2 to execute Wordcount program?

Answer (score 0):

2) When you copy a file from local to the HDFS it will be devided in chunkes and those chunks will be balanced and replicated over available datanodes (depending on configuration like replication factor etc).

3) No. The hadoop HDFS tools take care of distributing the data troughout the cluster. So when you only have two nodes, both should contain the whole file.

Comment: When I execute Wordcount on 1GB data on single standalone machine and same input on 1 cluster with 2 nodes it takes same time.